# Object Merge ShortCut

Tags: modeling, shortcut, edit-mode

I am faced with a problem about merging two object with clean topology in a short time.

I have looked for any shortcut or addon that solve this problem, but have as of yet been unlucky.

[image: surface]

Surface

[image: wire]

Wire

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please add more information about what you want to achieve. You may also have a look at the [toor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to ask well formulated questions which leads to best possible help from the community.

Comment: Merging two objects (in object mode) is done by selecting them both and "CTRL+J". But here you are allready in edit mode. So they are allready in one object so they are merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Idle Chit-chat

I have come up with a way of doing it that has many steps, but turns out a nice result.

### How to Do It

Start by selecting a single vertex of your sphere in *Edit Mode* and keying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select the rest of it. Then key <kbd>P</kbd> and click on *Selection*. This should se<kbd>P</kbd>arate your sphere from the cube mesh. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Object Mode*.

Now select the cube and go to the *Object modifiers* tab in the *Properties panel*. Add a *Boolean* modifier. Set the settings to the following. Substitute the name of your sphere mesh for where it says "[image]"

[image: Settings for Cube Boolean Modifier]

If you key <kbd>Z</kbd> to enter wireframe mode, your meshes should look something like this.

[image]

Apply the *Boolean* modifier by clicking the *Apply* button.

Make sure you are in *Orthographic View* (toggle with <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>). Key <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>, or <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> until you are looking at the side of the two meshes like this.

[image]

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*, toggle <kbd>Z</kbd> into wireframe view, and <kbd>B</kbd>ox select these verticies.

[image]

Key <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Verticies*. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Object Mode*. Key <kbd>R</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to rotate the hole in your cube away from the sphere.

Select the sphere and go to the *Object modifiers* tab in the *Properties panel*. Add a *Boolean* modifier. Set the settings to the following. Substitute the name of your cube mesh for where it says "[image]".

[image]

If you key <kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle wireframe view, your meshes should look something like this.

[image]

Apply the *Boolean* modifier by clicking the *Apply* button. Select the cube and key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. The hole on the side should go back to facing the sphere.

Select the sphere mesh, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RightMouseButton</kbd> select the cube mesh. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join the two. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*. Key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice to select all of both meshes, key <kbd>W</kbd>, and click on *Remove Doubles* from the popup menu.

Here is a finished .blend file with the two joined meshes.

[image]

Comment: The end result of this answer is achieved in 2 clicks by adding Boolean modifier set to *Difference* for both meshes, you'll end up with sphere cut off with cube and a hole between them. Whereas the OP asks about clean topology (which is definitely not the case with your solution). And how does that unclear Idle Chit-chat help to understand the answer ? What is its purpose ?

Comment: @MrZak My "Idle Chit-chat" has no purpose. It is purely meant to set the scene/be humorous. In fact, Google defines _idle_ as __without purpose or effect; pointless__.